# Implementing Reverse DNS in a Live Environment

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, reverse-dns

I've been tasked with implementing reverse DNS internally in our Windows environment. What are some risks I should watch out for, and what is the best way to setup a test environment for changes like these?

Should I just spin up a new domain controller and add a few DNS entries and then go from there? I'm a new sysadmin and just really want to avoid breaking something.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Active Directory don't use reverse DNS for any internal communication. There's absolutely no risk in setting up a reverse lookup zone.

You don't need a new Domain Controller. Just create the zone(s) on your existing DNS server(s).

Comment: Thanks! The new domain controller would just be for testing purposes. Just trying to be extra cautious.

Comment: There's no such thing as testing in a production environment. If you need to spin up a Domain Controller to tinker with, do it in a test environment. Deploy a new server, install the AD DS roles and services, and create a test domain.